# AHK Send Keys which are as Key defined

Tags: autohotkey

I have a problem while using a Hotkey from Ahk.
Im using this code to activate if `activated = 1` a piece of code

```
    l::
         if (activated = 1)
         {
              send, Hello there
         }
    else
        send, l
```

The problem is if `activated = 0` the l key wont press because itactivate it self.
Have anyone an idea how to solve it?
thanks SpaceBroetchen

Answer (score 2):

The `$` prefix<sup>[(docs)](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm#prefixdollar)</sup> is meant for this.
Makes it so the hotkey wont self trigger.
Also, I'd recommend [SendInput](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Send.htm#SendInputDetail), it's the faster and more reliable send mode.

```
$l::
    if (activated = 1)
        SendInput, Hello there
    else
        SendInput, l
return
```

Though, seems like an even better option would be to use a context sensitive hotkey for this.
If you want to tell me more about this `activated` check, I can probably recommend a better approach for this.

Comment: Thanks now it works, but the sendinput works only in a textdocument. The game where i want to use it dont react on it

Comment: As @SpaceBroetchen has noticed, while SendInput is more reliable for outputting text, it doesn't really work in applications like games. [Info about the different SendModes](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Send.htm#Send_variants). Just replace the `Sendinput`s in 0x464e's script with regular `Send`s and you should be fine. Also, if this does end up working, please mark 0x464e's answer as the accepted.